# URL to Publish to TeamCity NuGet server

Tags: powershell, nuget, teamcity

Trying to use PowerShell's `Publish-Module` to upload a PowerShell Module to TeamCity's NuGet server.
I can use PowerShell with `Find-Module` to find modules that were added to TeamCity from previous build artefacts, but would also like to upload "manually".

On other NuGet Servers I am used to see the `/Packages/` folder. Does that not exist on TeamCity?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to use Publish-Module from within a TeamCity build step?

Answer (score 0):

TeamCity NuGet feed is readonly. The only way to publish a package is running a build and publish it as an artifact.

Comment: Hi @lodkin , thanks. Is it planned to support this as an upcoming feature?